# Installed android app with eclipse working but install app with apk failed when launch?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have the following code that runs fine when I run it directly using eclipse. However when I export it as apk and install it, I cant launch it. It just keeps crashing.

```
    public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DB_NAME = "DB";
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    /** CREATE TABLE SQL */
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SQL = "";/*Create table statement*/

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        db = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SQL);
            Log.d("t", "database:"+DB_NAME+" created");
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
            db.close();
            super.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

What is the difference between installing it with eclipse vs installing with apk?

Thanks.

Regards,
Dexter

Comment: Where is your create table sql statment? And where is the SQL which actually "CREATE DATABASE"?

Comment: You should work with your logcat. And analyze it when installing apk through APK. by using "ADB LOGCAT" command.

Comment: Hi, the create statement is definitely correct since i the database is created with no problem. I removed it so that it is more easier to read. I found out that removing this line
db = getWritableDatabase(); and this line: SQLiteDatabase db; fixes the issue. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

**Question**
What is the difference between installing it with eclipse vs installing with apk?

**Answer**
Installing through `eclipse` is same as installing apk in device.

The difference is when you run ur project it will install `.apk` file in the emulator. You can see the `.apk` file `bin` folder the same `.apk` is insalled in emulator and u can take that apk and insall it in ur device.

When u install `.apk` file in device, your app may crash for various regions like..

1) Due to compatibility.

2) Due to screen resolution.

3) Due to large images which is not fitting for the particular layout, etc.